# Using assert statment to verify that item is not added to the cart, slenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to verify using assert statement that item is not being added to the cart. This is my selenium code:

```
public void verify_itemadded(String action) throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(session.driver, 40);
    switch(action) {
        case "added":
        case "not removed":
            WebElement itemVerify = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element("ItemVerify")));
            Assert.assertTrue("Item displayed in card",itemVerify.isDisplayed());
            if (itemVerify.isDisplayed()) {
                logger.info("Item displayed in cart");
            }
            break;
        case "not added":
            WebElement itemVerifyremove = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element("ScanOrLookup")));
            Assert.assertTrue("Item not displayed in card",!itemVerifyremove.isDisplayed());
            if (!itemVerifyremove.isDisplayed()) {
                logger.info("Item not displayed in cart");
            }
            break;

    }
```

I am getting as an error saying "Item not displayed in cart", whereas it should give that the test should pass.
Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: Add a break in case added.

Comment: Also print out and see what value isDisplayed() is printing.

Comment: Apparently `itemVerifyremove.isDiaplayed()` is `false`, you need to figure out why this method return false.